# Why is line highlighting not working in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to use [dracula theme](https://draculatheme.com/vim/) for vim and have installed it successfully using [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) on my [gnome-terminal](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal).

The issue that I am facing is that the current line and line numbers aren' translucently displayed as shown on the official site.

### How it should look like [image]

<sub>(source: [draculatheme.com](https://draculatheme.com/assets/img/screenshots/vim.png))</sub>

Notice how **Line 57** and the **line numbers side panel** are displayed a bit greyishly? It doesn't appear that way in my install. I am a beginner with vim so any help is appreciated.

Here are my [dotvim files](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/dotfiles/tree/d61ed4d8a90b71f4e4fb1a87100b2c2191f973d0) as a reference.

> **Update(13/01/2019)**: I am unable to provide the screenshot of this issue since it has been lost. I was able to fix the line highlighting by enabling `cursorline` for vim. To fix line number pane highlighting, I followed the instructions over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945518/number-pane-not-being-highlighted-in-vim-dracula-theme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me that screenshot looks like it was taken with `cursorline` enabled. Vim current line highlighting is enabled with:

```
:set cursorline
```

If that achieves the affect you're after, drop it in your vimrc. More info: `:help cursorline` and `:help cursorcolumn`.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thanks, but still I don't get a translucent highlighting effect. I get black line highlighting. You know why? Also, the line numbers aren't being highlighted.

Comment: Hrm, off the top of my head I got nothing. It may depend on whether your terminal (if you're using Vim in a terminal) colours are set up correctly, or some interaction between your environment and the theme. Not sure, sorry!

Comment: I found it. It was because `ctermbg` attribute of LineNr was set to none. More of it is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945518/number-pane-not-being-highlighted-in-vim).