# Number pane not being highlighted in vim dracula theme

Tags: vim, customization, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am using [dracula](https://draculatheme.com/vim) theme for vim and am not able to get the number pane, that is, the side panel which contains the line numbers, to be displayed in a sort of translucent manner. The preview image shows that it's possible.

### How the terminal should look like [image]

<sub>(source: [draculatheme.com](https://draculatheme.com/assets/img/screenshots/vim.png))</sub>

### How it actually looks

[image]

To fix this issue, I think I need to configure some attributes accordingly, but being a beginner, I don't know which ones, therefore any help and guidance would be appreciated.

As a reference, these are my [dotvim files](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/dotfiles-kde-i3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background of the line numbers column is [set in the colorscheme](https://github.com/dracula/vim/blob/master/colors/dracula.vim#L28) to `NONE` for color terminals and `#282a36` for GUIs:

```
hi LineNr ctermfg=60 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#6272a4 guibg=#282a36 gui=NONE
```

From there you have three options:

- Enable the `'termguicolors'` option so that Vim uses the `gui*` attributes instead of the `cterm*` attributes.

  This is how the screenshot was taken but it will only work [in select terminal emulators](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728).

  See `:help 'termguicolors'`.
- Edit the colorscheme directly:

  ```
  hi LineNr ctermfg=60 ctermbg=242 cterm=NONE guifg=#6272a4 guibg=#282a36 gui=NONE
  ```

  I've chosen `242` arbitrarily but you can choose whatever color you want in [this chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg)
- [Override your colorscheme](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f) in your `vimrc`:

  ```
  function! MyHighlights() abort
      hi LineNr ctermfg=60 ctermbg=242 cterm=NONE guifg=#6272a4 guibg=#282a36 gui=NONE
  endfunction

  augroup MyColors
      autocmd!
      autocmd ColorScheme * call MyHighlights()
  augroup END
  colorscheme dracula
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I am a total beginner with `vim` and I wasn't able to find anything about this. This helped a lot, plus I learn a new coding method as well :).